# Local Development - Authorization in Node.js App after Authentication with AWS Cognito and ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

we have setup a simple Node.js App on ElasticBeanstalk with an additional **authentication Step** on an Application Load Balancer in front of the app using *AWS Cognito*.

This is working just fine, Users get authenticated so that
the Application receives the headers `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken`, `x-amzn-oidc-identity` and `x-amzn-oidc-data` forwarded by the ALB.

Now we need an **authorization Step** (ABAC - Attribute based Access) on the JWT supplied by the ALB.
The Application shall only be useable depending on an email attribute, contained in the headers.

How can we develop this locally and debug it? Headers are only supplied in AWS so they are not available without ALB. Is there any Framework to simulate or mock these Headers?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Struggling with the same concept.

Comment: Nope, we have captured a token from a request and mapped it locally.
Goes into the direction of the answer below

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So frustrating that there's no tooling to help with this.
So just to be clear; you have to repeat this process every time the access token expires? Or are you conditionally not running the verification step in local mode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about the knowledge of other users, but as far as I know, it doesn't exist.
I think it's simple to test or debug by reusing the header information actually given by ALB as a local request.