# AWS Load Balancer Authentication with Cognito Testing

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, load-balancing

I'd like to use an Application Load Balancer (ALB) to authenticate requests with Cognito to my node express back-end. After authenticating, the ALB maintains session with a session cookie, and will forward a few headers to the back-end in form x-amzn-oidc-* (e.g. x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken).

My application backend needs these claims to carry out requests. So how do I develop and test token signature verification locally?

Edit:

- Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67458393/13637369).
- Headers containing identifying information and access tokens [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#user-claims-encoding)